# Computations on matrix and avoiding division by zero

Tags: awk, data

I want to compute average of values in data table

Example data matrix

```
S1  1   3   4   5   16  3   3   4   6   0
S2  1   6   4   5   16  3   4   6   6   0
S3  1   3   4   3   4   7   3   5   16  9
S4  0   0   4   5   6   0   0   4   5   6
```

The idea is to divide `col7` by `col2`, `col8` by `col3` and so on until `col11` by `col11`

**Expected output**

```
S1  0.75    0.5 0.5 0.545455    0
S2  0.75    0.4 0.6 0.545455    0
S3  0.875   0.5 0.555556    0.842105    0.692308
S4  0  0  0.5  0.5  0.5
```

awk script

```
cat TestFile  | awk '{ out=$1; for(i=2;i<=6;i++) out=out"\t"$(i+5)/($i+$(i+5)); print out }'
```

**Output from command**

```
S1  0.75    0.5 0.5 0.545455    0
S2  0.75    0.4 0.6 0.545455    0
S3  0.875   0.5 0.555556    0.842105    0.692308
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

It throws error due to division by "0".

When there is division by 0, how to pad "0" without error message.

Comment: Please describe your problem accurately. You are not dividing col(i) by col(i+5). The operation you are doing is col(i+5)/(col(i+5)+col(i)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 awk '{for (i=2;i<=6;i++) $i = ($(i+5)!=0? $(i+5)/($i+$(i+5)): 0); NF=6} 1' file
```

We use a [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html), where we test the divisor before the division, if it is zero, we assign a value without dividing and raising error. Also for printing only the first 6 columns, it is enough to assign `NF=6` and print the record.

---

To allign your expected output, you can define the output field separator to <kbd>Tab</kbd> using `awk -v OFS='\t'` or you can pipe the output to `colun -t` for a tab-like look, filled with spaces.

```
S1  0.75   0.5  0.5       0.545455  0
S2  0.75   0.4  0.6       0.545455  0
S3  0.875  0.5  0.555556  0.842105  0.692308
S4  0      0    0.5       0.5       0.5
```

Comment: For the requested formatting, add `-vOFS="\t"` (or in a BEGIN rule).